# Keil uVision4 armcc: Using C++ standard includes <cstdint>

Tags: c++, include, stm32, keil

I am using Keil uVision4 to develop on a STM32F2 device.
I am trying to use C++, which should be possible with the armcc (correct me if I am wrong) supplied with the uVision toolchain.
But uVision refuses to accept the standard C++ include way

```
    #include <cstdint>
```

doesnt work while

```
    #include <stdint.h>
```

works perfectly.
When i open cstdint inside uVision (rightclick, open document ) , it opens the file, but as generic file, e.g. not as header file, without the fancy colors.

What am I missing? Both files are in the same folder
C:\Keil\ARM\ARMCC\include
and it doesnt make any difference whether I force the Compiler to use c++ (by appending --cpp) or not.
Is uVision just unable to accept files without endings as header files?

Edit: In response to the answers (thank you for your time!):
The error message would be:

```
    #include <cstdint> and
    #include <cstdint.h>
    typedef uint32_t u32;
    error: #20: identifier uint32_t is undefined
```

while

```
    #include <stdint.h> and
    #include <stdint>
    typedef uint32_t u32;
    and 
    #include <cstdint> 
    typedef std::uint32_t u32;
    works perfectly.
```

which shows what the problem is. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try making a copy of `cstdint` and calling it `cstdint.h` (not as a solution, but to test your theory)

Comment: you know that `<cstdint>` was just added to C++11, right? It's not part of C++98 nor C++03

Answer (score 1):

What symptoms are you getting to it not working? I.e. what is the error message? It may be that you only need a `using namespace std`, or to prefix std:: in front of all the types, since the `cstdint` header places its declarations in the `std` namespace.

Note however, that `cstdint` is a very new header, and may not be supported by your compiler. So you may have to settle for `stdint.h`, which is just as good.